# Linux shell: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Tags: linux, matlab, shell, grammar

It is a for loop with three levels, for three arrays:

```
u in userdim=(67 133 200)

i in itemdim=(78 156 234)

t in tagdim=(50 100 150).


matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r "matlab_function('folderA/txtFile1.txt','folderB/txtFile[${userdim[${u}]} ${itemdim[${i}]} ${tagdim[${t}]}].txt',[${userdim[${u]} ${itemdim[${i}]} ${tagdim[${t}]}],2)"
# echo "u=$[${u}+1]; i=${i}; t=${t}"
```

Its result is

```
line 24: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

line 30: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Is there something wrong with the "matlab..." line? Especially with the single quotation marks?

Comment: In order to produce a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), you should reduce your program to the samllest size without losing the error. Then you can post this program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a valid for loop - is that just to show us what the values of your arrays are? Regardless, your matlab line does have an error:

```
[${userdim[${u]} ${itemdim[${i}]} ${tagdim[${t}]}]
```

Should be:

```
[${userdim[${u}]} ${itemdim[${i}]} ${tagdim[${t}]}]
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I never programmed on linux shell before but that was a stupid mistake hehe   thanks!